# British Person or English Person?

Tags: politeness

Are there grammatical etiquette guidelines as to whether to refer to a person from Great Britain as a British person or an English person? Is referring to a person as a Brit insulting, even if no insult was intended?

Comment: It's not a matter of grammar. The issue is that Great Britain has three distinct parts: England,  Scotland, and Wales.

Comment: I doubt anyone from the UK will take offence at being called British or a Brit. Calling a Scot, English might cost you a few teeth however so stick to Brit until you know for sure where they are from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Brits call themselves Brits.
It's just an abbreviation, not a derogatory term.
You could avoid it if being formal, but in everyday conversation it's fine.

You could further sub-divide into English, Scottish [or Scots... never scotch, that's a drink not a person] & Welsh, but you'd need to be certain which they actually were.
It's easier not to guess & just refer to them as British.

Comment: Not all Bitish people call themselves Brits, and some dislike the word. See this thread: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/25289/is-it-appropriate-to-call-a-british-person-a-brit

Comment: I admit it's a bit 'tabloid', with hints of 'Brits Abroad' & Union Jack swimming trunks - but I've heard its use in everyday conversation for years, & I refer to myself as a Brit with no qualms.

Comment: @Tesujin. Like you, I refer to myself (informally) as a Brit, and have no objection to being referred to as such However, I know several Brits who are not happy with the word.

Comment: So, it sounds as if British person & English person are synonymous, although British person is the most widely used. Concerning the use of the term, Brit, some excellent comments are posted. *Joe Dark* doubts anyone would take offense. *Tetsujin* has no objection. *tunny* gives a link that some dislike the word. Conversing with someone with whom I'm on familiar & friendly terms, sure, it would be okay. If in doubt whether the other person would be offended, it would be best to say English person.

Comment: Not if they are not English - that's the whole point. 'Britain' comprises three countries.

Answer (score 2):

Grammatically, it's not incorrect if we say a British person or an English person, but such phrases seem a bit awkward. I think it's common and natural if we just say "He is British" if he is from Britain. However, we can say "the British" to mean people from Britain. If a person is from England, the usual word is Englishman.

Answer (score 0):

Scots and the Welsh and the Northern Irish are not English, but they are British. Ironically, the Cornish are English but Cornish is not English.:-)

Comment: When you say "Cornish is not English", am I right in assuming that you are referring to the languages?

Comment: That is correct.